# NSCoding class with properties that may not implement NSCoding

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

What is the proper way to handle this situation?

I want to implement NSCoding in my class Foo, but it has one generic property called bar of type "id".

```
@interface Foo : NSObject <NSCoding> {
    id bar;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) id bar;

@end
```

If that property doesn't happen to implement NSCoding, I don't want to encode an incomplete representation of my object, so how do I fail gracefully (keeping in mind that my object may be being encoded as part of a larger graph)?

Classes like NSDictionary have no requirement that their contents implement NSCoding, and yet they do, so there must be a way to handle this case?

Answer (score 0):

Yes;  either don't encode `bar` or encode something that represents `bar`.

If you attempt to encode a collection class instance that contains non-coding compliant objects, it will barf.

Comment: I guess I can test it, but in what way will it barf?  Invalid selector?  So why wouldn't NSDictionary and other collections accept only objects of type id<NSCoding>?  Or if they didn't, why wouldn't they mention that adding non-compliant objects will cause crashes in their docs?

Comment: Sorry one more question.  What do you mean by "encode something that represents bar"?  You mean just an empty placeholder?  Thanks.